# Call variable from within overridden method but it may not have been initialized

Tags: java, android

Consider the following declarations:

```
public final class MyClass {
    public MyClass(AnotherClass var) {
        /* implementation not shown */
    }

    public void invoke() {
        /* implementation not shown */
    }

    /* there may be more methods/properties listed */
}

public class AnotherClass() {
    public AnotherClass() {
        /* implementation not shown */
    }

    public void method() {
        /* implementation not shown */
    }

    /* there may be more methods/properties listed */
}
```

The implementations of both classes may not be changed.

Now consider the following piece of code:

```
final MyClass myVariable = new MyClass(anotherVariable);

AnotherClass anotherVariable = new AnotherClass() {
    @Override
    public void method() {
        myVariable.invoke();
    }
};
```

Clearly it cannot be run because `anotherVariable` is not ready at the first line, but if I rearrange the two statements...

```
AnotherClass anotherVariable = new AnotherClass() {
    @Override
    public void method() {
        myVariable.invoke();
    }
};

final MyClass myVariable = new MyClass(anotherVariable);
```

Then, `myVariable` may not have been initialized, and it still doesn't work.

How could I make this work?

---

A real world example would be (from android):

```
final MediaScannerConnection msc = new MediaScannerConnection(this,
                new MediaScannerConnection.MediaScannerConnectionClient() {
                    @Override
                    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri){
                        msc.disconnect();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onMediaScannerConnected() {
                        msc.scanFile("", null);
                    }
                });
msc.connect();
```

Comment: The above code will only work if you instantiate it as a global variable not in local scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to do it:

```
AnotherClass anotherVariable = new AnotherClass() {
    private MyClass myVariable;

    public void setMyVariable(MyClass myVariable) {
        this.myVariable = myVariable;
    }

    @Override
    public void method() {
        this.myVariable.invoke();
    }
};

MyClass myVariable = new MyClass(anotherVariable);
anotherVariable.setMyVariable(myVariable);
anotherVariable.method();
```

---

As for your Android example, it would probably make more sense to call `scanFile` after calling `connect`, and use the [`scanFile`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html#scanFile(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String[],%20android.media.MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener)) method that accepts a [`MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener.html) callback.